# wears my like clockwork meta hat?

Tags: discussion, meta, winter-bash

I have visited Mathematics Meta 10 days on the trot, but I don't seem to have a hat for this.

Why is that?

Comment: Perhaps badge-hunters incur a (-1) hat penalty.

Comment: Was the title intended to start *wears* or *Where's* (my ... hat)?

Comment: @user296602: ...and that's why I hate this whole shebang. Badge gamers (badgers? I'm gonna start using badgers) require more dedication, and can maintain mostly-invisible effect on the site. The hat gamers (haters?) have to cram their efforts into a couple of weeks, making everything much more... ugh.

Answer (score 4):

You don't earn hats on Meta, and you usually also don't get hats *for* things you do on Meta, unless the hat specifically says "do X on meta". Quoting myself from [Why didn't (or did) I or some other user get a hat although the requirements were (or weren't) fulfilled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer),

> Most hats are awarded for things you do on the main site, but there are a few* that are awarded for performing an action on the site's meta. Their requirement generally includes the words "on meta". You still earn these hats *on the main site*, but you earn them for doing something on its child meta.

<sub>* This year there aren't any.</sub>